# How can the apes understand Caesar's English?

Tags: planet-of-the-apes, planet-of-the-apes-2011, war-for-the-planet-of-the-apes

In *War for the Planet of the Apes* (2017),  Caesar speaks English to his ape army, but how Apes can understand English too?

Comment: I don't have a very extensive answer, but while teaching all the apes Ape Sign Caesar may have taught them English as well. Caesar is also seen using sign language in the film and may have used that for the apes that didn't know English. Lastly the apes in Caesars colony are (I believe) all genetically enhanced to be smarter. So it's possible they learn much quicker, but as seen with Bad Ape even ordinary zoo Apes are able to learn English from listening to the zookeepers.

Comment: Note that there is a base justification for the apes speaking and understanding English (i.e. genetic enhancement). The absence of communication problems (bad understanding, misinterpretation, ...) is a common occurrence in movies when it's not important to the plot, because it distracts from the plot for no good reason.